# Timezone offset rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, offset

In rails how to get the exect day after adding offset

```
irb(main):066:0> DateTime.now.utc
=> Sat, 29 Mar 2014 19:12:57 +0000
```

after adding `5.30 hours` it should show 30 march. why it is 29 again .anything I missed here

```
irb(main):065:0> DateTime.now.utc.change(:offset => "+0530")
=> Sat, 29 Mar 2014 19:09:03 +0530
```

Comment: I think all you did was shift the zone.  What happens when you try `DateTime.now.utc + 5.hours + 30.minutes`?  The `.utc` part only really affects the display and `+0530` in your suggests its just moving from UTC to a time zone offset of 5:30.

Comment: thanks a lot rdnewman. I thought it will change the date part also. is there any standard way in rails to do this ? else adding hours and minutes is the right way. I am a newbie on this thing. Plase help me understand

Comment: Usually I use ActiveSupport::Durations to add hours/minutes.  So a way would be `(DateTime.now + 5.hours + 30.minutes).utc`  The use of Duration helpers is a common idiom.   `.utc` is usually just needed for display since a date as a model attribute is usually stored UTC anyway and converted to your TimeZone by convention (and so you use `.utc` to convert it back).

Comment: I read you earlier comment a bit closer.  Just to be sure:  adding `5.hours` and `30.minutes` literally adds 330 minutes.  If that takes you into a new date, then you'll see that.  The use of `.hours` and `.minutes` is just syntactic sugar for readable code.  I'm sorry if I'm being pedantic, but I didn't want you to think that it saying `5.hours` somehow only affected hours and not the date or what have you.  The underlying time storage is the conventional seconds since the start of the epoch.

Comment: thank you rdnewman, for your clear reply

Comment: Hi rdnewman, if ppossible please have a look into this question too and correct me if I did anything wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748505/how-to-store-timezone-info-in-rails