# How to store timezone info in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, timezone, offset, sunspot

In my rails application,users can create questions and publish that, anybody from any country can response for that.
 We are designing database structure for that. so planning to get user timezone using some js and while answering converting that time and to store in a separate column(tz_created_at). 
 so in created at the date will be stored in utc format, and in another column say tz_created_at the datetime will be stored as user's timezone converted time. (ie) in created_at column i have 
 irb(main):013:0> DateTime.now.utc => Sun, 30 Mar 2014 18:54:46 +0000

And in tz_created_at column i have
 irb(main):015:0> DateTime.now
+ 6.hours(from user's timezone) => Mon, 31 Mar 2014 06:58:31 +0600

we are using sunspot solr to show some statistics in response over the time period.

so while querying for responses for a particular question i will search in tz_created_at column. is this approach is correct . please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, you probably want to store the datetime as UTC, then store the user's timezone in another column. By doing that you can always change the timezone if you need to without affecting the true time (e.g. the user moves country). When you display a time to the user you can easily convert the time to their zone to display it.

If you're a subscriber of railscasts there's a [video on it there](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised), but if you're not a subscriber there's [an older one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1) that's free to watch that will give you a general idea of best practices.

Comment: Actually there is one filter in our application, which will display the number of responses in a specific day.in this case how to achieve this

Comment: You could use dates created with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` to generate times in the user's time zone, but which can be converted to utc to query the database. Try this: `my_time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Sydney"].parse("2013-04-03 00:00:00")`. You should get a time object that is midnight in Sydney. You could use that to create specific time windows for the time zone you're concerned about. To get utc you just do `my_time.utc`

Comment: So what I am going to do is for from date in date filter, irb(main):017:0> ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Asia/Kolkata"].parse("2013-04-27 00:00:00").utc
=> 2013-04-26 18:30:00 UTC
for to_date in date filter irb(main):031:0> ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Asia/Kolkata"].parse("2013-04-27 23:59:59").utc
using this dates i am going to query the DB and solr. Am I correct?

Comment: The dates look good yeah. I'm not that familiar with solr so you'll just have to test that carefully but it looks good in principle